# PHP unpack question

Tags: php, sphinx, binary-data

```
list(,$nfields) = unpack ( "N*", substr ( $response, $p, 4 ) ); $p += 4;
```

The question is, why `"N*"` if `substr` should return 4 bytes, and they will be unpacked as N? And why double assignment?

**UPD**: This code is part of [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) native PHP connector. After some code hacking it became clear that this code extracts 4-byte integer. But logic behind double assignment and `substr` / `N*` is still unclear to me. I'm offering a bounty to finally understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd need to see the revision history of the file but some possibilities are:

1. These are the remains of a previous algorithm that was progressively stripped of functionality but never cleaned up.
2. It's the typical spaghetti code we all produce after a bad night.
3. It's an optimization that speeds up the code for large input strings.

These are all synonyms:

```
<?php

$packed = pack('N*', 100, 200, 300);

// 1
var_dump( unpack('N*', $packed) );

// 2
var_dump( unpack('N*', substr($packed, 0, 4)) );
var_dump( unpack('N*', substr($packed, 4, 4)) );
var_dump( unpack('N*', substr($packed, 8, 4)) );

// 3
var_dump( unpack('N', substr($packed, 0, 4)) );
var_dump( unpack('N', substr($packed, 4, 4)) );
var_dump( unpack('N', substr($packed, 8, 4)) );

?>
```

I did the typical repeat-a-thousand-times benchmark with three integers and **1** is way faster. However, a similar test with 10,000 integers shows that **1** is the slowest :-!

```
0.82868695259094 seconds
0.0046610832214355 seconds
0.0029149055480957 seconds
```

Being a full-text engine where performance is a must, I'd dare say it's an optimization.

Answer (score 0):

The code is probably a bug. This kind of loop is precisely the reason why `*` exists...

Comment: This code works :) And I need to understand _how_. Should `substr` cut off exactly 4 bytes? What with multibyte strings?

Comment: `substr` is not multibyte-aware, `mb_substr` is.

Comment: @Victor: That's why `substr` cuts 4 bytes, not 4 mb chars.

Answer (score 0):

> unpack ( "N*", substr ( $response, $p,
>   4 ) );

Specifies the format to use when unpacking the data from substr()

N - unsigned long, always 32 bit, big endian byte order